# exit shell script when a process check is failed

Tags: bash, scripts

i need to exit from shell script when TESTEXCHANGE process is not running on a host.How can i handle this:

I have a script processcheck which checks if the process is running.

I call that to the MainTest script.I want to exit MainTest script if the ProcessCheck script fails.

`cat Processcheck`:

```bsh
while read proc; do
        if (( 0 == $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c /location) )); then
                echo "!!!!! $proc down on Master TU  !!!!!"
                RC=1
         else
           echo "!!!!!! $proc is still running on Master TU!!!!!"
        fi
#echo "Not checked"

done < /tmp/PROCESSLIST
```

`cat MainTest`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

cd /app/utp/bin

ssh Test@TestHost 'bash -s' < /ProcessCheck
```

i want to exit here if processcheck fails
next steps

Comment: What do you mean, "fail" ? You mean when ProcessCheck detects an error and prints `!!!!! $proc down on Master TU  !!!!!`, or when it misbehaves and returns an error ?

Comment: @Ploutox when it prints "$proc down on Master TU !!!!!,"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use exit statuses to deal with your case. [Exit statuses](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) are numerical values returned by a command to indicate whether the execution went well or not. The default value is `0` if it was a success, a number between `[1..255]` otherwise. Each value has a [signification](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html).

For instance, you could rewrite your `Processcheck` like this :

```
while read proc; do
        if (( 0 == $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -c /location) )); then
                echo "!!!!! $proc down on Master TU  !!!!!"
                RC=1  #I'm not sure why you use this line
                EXIT_STATUS=1
         else
           echo "!!!!!! $proc is still running on Master TU!!!!!"
        fi
#echo "Not checked"

done < /tmp/PROCESSLIST
exit $EXIT_STATUS  #1 means there was an error, 0 means everything went fine
```

In your `MainTest`, you can call `Processcheck` and check its status by looking the variable `$?`